# Tasker duty cycling wifi profile

Tags: tasker

I'm trying to get the hang of Tasker but failing a bit.
I was wondering if somebody could explain how to create the following profile? I think if I manage to go through an intermediate profile, I'll understand it better.

So basically, I want a profile that duty cycles my Wifi/Location/PowerSaving mode when the display is off or the device is locked and do so differently depending on the time of day.

What this means is the following:

**If day (say from 6:30-22:30)**

=>Then if the screen is locked or the display is off for longer than X seconds (say 60s)

====>Then disable wifi, location and enable powersaving

====> And

====> Every 3 minutes, activate wifi and location for X seconds and turn off again(enough to ====>retrieve email, facebook messages,  etc... I think 15 seconds?)

**Else (so if it is night, not day)**

=>Then if the screen is locked or the display is off for longer than X seconds (say 60s)

====>Then disable wifi, location and enable powersaving

====> And

====> Every 30 minutes, activate wifi and location for X seconds and turn off again(enough to ====>retrieve email, facebook messages,  ====>etc... I think 15 seconds?)

So, can somebody help me set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the XML of a Tasker Profile and Tasks that cycle WiFi on the cycle you describe above, as well as screen shots. The only difference between the Day and Night tasks is the time between Wifi Enable. GPS and Power Saving are abit more tricky. GPS may require root and Power Saving depends heavily on the phone make/model.

XML File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzsMV39gBg6rZXZQdnhGTmEwNm8/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]